# How to write to .txt files in Python 3

Tags: python, file, text, file-io

I have a `.txt` file in the same folder as this `.py` file and it has this in it:

```
cat\n
dog\n
rat\n
cow\n
```

How can I save a var (var = 'ant') to the next line of the `.txt` file?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Open the file in append mode and write a new line (including a `\n` line separator):

```
with open(filename, 'a') as out:
    out.write(var + '\n')
```

This adds the line at the end of the file after all the other contents.

Answer (score 17):

Just to be complete on this question:

You can also use the [print function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

```
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    print(var, file=f)
```

The print function will automatically end each print with a newline (unless given an alternative ending in the call, for example `print(var, file=f, end='')` for no newlines).